# Database not updated with 3g but works fine with Wi-Fi

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, caching

I am suppose to update the online database. Ive realise that when my network is connected to the Wi-Fi, the database gets updated when I press the refresh button, however when my network is connected to the 3g, the database may or may not gets updated. If it gets updated, it would take a long time, even if i pressed the refresh button.. I think there is problem with the caching but Im not sure how to put the caching into my code.. This is my code:

```
- (void)downloadAtURLString:(NSString *)urlString
{
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    self.activeDownload = data;
    [data release];
    // encode the urlString with percent escapes
    NSString *urlStr = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlStr];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    self.urlConnection = conn;
    [conn release], [request release], [url release];
 }
```

I tried using this code:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:30.0];
```

I received a warning.. is the cachePolicy correct??

Comment: does not matter.. the latest i tried was by adding an alphabet to the existing chunk of data available.

Comment: Have you tried to Set the cache policy to NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData for testing purpose..

Comment: Hey @MaxBallo Im actually quite new to this caching stuff.. do you mind telling me specifically where am I suppose to put the cache policy.. Ive seen examples of this cache policy but when I tried to implement it, it dosent work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? This example ignores the local cache of the request.

```
- (void)downloadAtURLString:(NSString *)urlString
{
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    self.activeDownload = data;
    [data release];
    // encode the urlString with percent escapes
    NSString *urlStr = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlStr];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    self.urlConnection = conn;
    [conn release], [request release], [url release];
 }
```

Also include the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` in your class and implement the [delegate functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to get a feedback from the NSURLConnection.